# How to connect and accessing mysqldb with ruby programming

Tags: mysql, ruby

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
require "rubygems"
require "mysql"
begin
     # connect to the MySQL server
     dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:TESTDB:localhost", 
                        "nyros", "root")
     # get server version string and display it
     row = dbh.select_one("SELECT VERSION()")
     puts "Server version: " + row[0]
rescue DBI::DatabaseError => e
     puts "An error occurred"
     puts "Error code:    #{e.err}"
     puts "Error message: #{e.errstr}"
ensure
     # disconnect from server
     dbh.disconnect if dbh
end
```

I want to connect and access MySQL database through ruby programming. But i am getting this error when executing the ruby code in my terminal.

Error:

```
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3 p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require': cannot load such file -- mysql (LoadError)
from /home/nyros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
from task.rb:3:in '<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2). It is a mysql library for Ruby.

For example:

```
require 'mysql2'

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => HOST, :username => USERNAME, :database => DATABASE)
client.query("select * from tabel_name;")
```

If you don't want to use `mysql2`, you also can refer to this [link](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlrubytutorial/).